# How did $X^{2}-(4+K)X+9 $ become $(4+K)^{2}-36$?

Tags: calculus

[Need help with part b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsuyT.png)

I got all the way to $x^2-(4+K)x+9=0$ but I don't get how they got $(4+K)^2-36=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then the roots become $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}$. Now  notice that both the roots will be equal if ${b^2-4ac=0}$. In your case it becomes $(4+K)^2-36=0$.  Hope it helps